# Error trying to build docker for flask app

Tags: python, docker, flask, pytorch, jinja2

I'm trying to build a docker to run a flask app. I've never done this before. I have the flask app working locally. Here is my approach:

My directory structure for the project looks like this:

```
model.pkl  README.md          images/            static/
Dockerfile         flaskapp.py        requirements.txt   templates/
```

I can launch the flask app by running `python flaskapp.py` and it runs in my browser (locally).

I want to create a Docker so other machines can run this project without dealing with all the dependency stuff. To do so, I've done the following:

- I created a Dockerfile with this inside:

```
FROM python:3
COPY requirements.txt /tmp
COPY flaskapp.py /tmp
COPY model.pkl /tmp
COPY images /tmp
COPY static /tmp
COPY templates /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp
ADD flaskapp.py /
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD [ "python", "flaskapp.py" ]
```

- Ran the command `docker build -t python-barcode .`
- That worked, so. I ran `docker run python-barcode`. The terminal printed out `* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`, but it didn't work and I got this error on the browser:

```
This site can’t be reached0.0.0.0 refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

So I did some digging and I updated my Dockerfile to this (adding the last line):

```
FROM python:3
COPY requirements.txt /tmp
COPY flaskapp.py /tmp
COPY model.pkl /tmp
COPY images /tmp
COPY static /tmp
COPY templates /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp
ADD flaskapp.py /
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD [ "python", "flaskapp.py" ]
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0" ]
```

- Then running `docker run python-barcode` again, I get this error:

```
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not locate Flask application. You did not provide the FLASK_APP environment variable.

For more information see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/quickstart/
```

How should I proceed?

If its relevant, my `flaskapp.py` looks like this:

```
model = load_learner('', 'model.pkl')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0

def classify(document):
    X = document
    y = model.predict(X)
   
    return y

class ReviewForm(Form):
    pred = TextAreaField('',[validators.DataRequired(),validators.length(min=1)])

@app.route('/')
def index():
    form = ReviewForm(request.form)
    return render_template('reviewform.html', form=form)

@app.route('/results', methods=['POST'])
def results():
    form = ReviewForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        sequence = request.form['pred']
        y = classify(sequence)
        return render_template('results.html',
        y = y)
    return render_template('reviewform.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0')
```

#### EDIT 1

Now I am getting this error:

```
[2020-07-03 00:29:51,222] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "flaskapp.py", line 94, in index
    return render_template('reviewform.html', form=form)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 133, in render_template
    return _render(ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 930, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 883, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 857, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 115, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 57, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 85, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: reviewform.html
```

Comment: Are you setting the FLASK_APP environment variable anywhere?

Comment: no, i dont know what that means.

Comment: I ran export FLASK_APP=flaskapp.py in the terminal, but I get the same error. Should I run export FLASK_APP=flaskapp.py somewhere else?

Comment: try running export FLASK_APP=flaskapp

Comment: Same error. I'm running this in the terminal, is that right?

Comment: Yes. But if you're using Docker, you should add it to the Dockerfile instead

Comment: if you want you can add `ENV  FLASK_APP=flaskapp.py` as a directive in the  dockerfile ... but that doesnt actually resolve your issue ... you will be right back where you were when you just did `python my_app.py`

Comment: I am confused, how should I proceed here? What should I add, if anything, to the Dockerfile?

Comment: the error is now different `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: reviewform.html` check the template as it complaining not foud.

Comment: I think you can ask another question as this error has nothing to do with `docker`? docker issue has been resolved ;)

Comment: @Adiii the file exists in the folder `templates`, which I thought I was adding in the Dockerfile with COPY templates /tmp

Comment: I see, then copy `flaskapp.py` to correct path `ADD flaskapp.py /tmp` and it should work.

Comment: Aren't I already doing this? See the first Dockerfile in my post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217111/discussion-between-adiii-and-connor449).

Answer (score 1):

You can have only `CMD` per Dockerfile. so one will likely be ignored.

```
CMD [ "python", "flaskapp.py" ]
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0" ]
```

Just remove the second one as you already listening to all interfaces in the code.

```
CMD [ "python", "flaskapp.py" ]
```

Now run the Docker container with this command.

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 -it python-barcode
```

And then you will able to hit endpoint

htpp://localhost:5000

Comment: he doesnt actually need to listen to all interfaces when running inside a docker as the port forwarding will resolve that ... but yes :) good answer on exposing the port :P

Comment: I did this and I get this error on the browser: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: look at the output ... you should have a traceback ...

Comment: Its mean the error from application side, check your code, or check docker logs `docker logs -f container_nam`, now your container is reachable and its responding to client

Comment: @JoranBeasley no port forwading will not work as application will receive docker gateway IP not the localhost, also if remove all interfaces from the code you will  `* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)` so you will not able to reached container even if you expose the port.

Comment: you might be right ... its been a while since i messed with this ... but i can believe it ... I thought that it was forwarding from external port to internal port with localhost ... but i can entirely believe im wrong

Comment: I will concede entirely that you are correct it does need all interfaces :P (I just tested to verify)

Comment: yeah one easy to verify this is print the IP from request and you will see docker gateway IP.

Answer (score 0):

you need to expose the port to the external world

`docker run -p 8000:8000 python-barcode` this maps port 8000 inside the docker container to port 8000 outside the docker container.

then you can go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000` on the host computer

you could also redirect the port to a different port

`docker run -p 8000:9000 python-barcode` and then access it at `http://127.0.0.1:9000` on the host system

Comment: I get the same error when running this command: Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not locate Flask application. You did not provide the FLASK_APP environment variable.

Comment: get rid of that line ... just use the `python my_app.py` bit  (although you might need `['/bin/python','my_app.py']`

Comment: I'm confused by this, what do you mean?

Comment: you need to have the left side be the port that Flask is serving on (its actually probably 5000), the right side is the port you want to expose ... get rid of the `CMD ['flask','run']` line and just use the `CMD ['python', 'my_app.py']` line

Comment: Okay, I did this and am now getting another error. See edit 1 in my og post. Its saying I dont have reviewform.html, which is located in the templates folder. Why is this happening, as I copy it in the Dockerfile?

Comment: do `docker run -it  python-barcode bash` and `ls /tmp` .. you can also try things until it works in the shell like that